# While fetching the Audit Log Programmatically, last Downloaded document is not fetched from Auditing Log

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

**Configuration** : Auditing enabled to "Viewing or Downloading Documents" at Site Collection Level

Below Code Used to Fetch the last 30 minutes of Audit Log

```
SPList list = web.Lists["MyLibrary"];

SPAuditQuery wssQuery = new SPAuditQuery(SPContext.Current.Web.Site);
wssQuery.RestrictToUser(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID);
wssQuery.AddEventRestriction(SPAuditEventType.View);
wssQuery.RestrictToList(list)       

//set the query date range
wssQuery.SetRangeEnd(DateTime.Now);
wssQuery.SetRangeStart(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30));// To get the last 30 Mins of data

SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Audit.GetEntries(wssQuery);
```

---

Steps to replicate the issue:

1. Download 3 documents sequentially
2. Pause for 15 seconds
3. Downloaded next 2  documents sequentially
4. Executed my above mentioned program

Result : Fetched only first 3 documents, documents which are downloaded after pause is not retrieved

1. Do Page Refresh

Result : I can See 5 Documents

**Question** :

Is Most recent download event pushed into Content DB by other relevant event ?? 
(Event : Page Refresh /New Download / Custom Report Generation etc ).

What is the solution to fetch the all downloaded event Programmatically ?

Kindly let me know anybody can reproduce this issue atleast ?